# 画像URL入力または画像ファイルをアップロード→読み込んだ画像をcanvasに送る→描画を開始させたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**画像URL入力または画像ファイルをアップロード→読み込んだ画像をcanvasに送る→描画開始**
というコードを作りたいです。
[現状](https://jsbin.com/wusacahito/6/edit?html,js,output)、画像URLまたはローカルの画像ファイルをアップロードする形で、canvasに画像を描画することはできていますが、

```
$(function () {
//input url
$('#url').change(function () {
    var url = $('#url').val();
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        $('#canvas').fadeOut(1);
        var file = $('#file')[0];
        file.value = "";
        $('#canvas').fadeIn(1);
        var cnvsH = 250;
        var cnvsW = img.naturalWidth * cnvsH / img.naturalHeight;
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', cnvsW);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', cnvsH);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, cnvsW, cnvsH);
    }
    img.src = url;
});
//input file
$('#file').change(function () {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var img = new Image();
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function (e) {
        img.onload = function () {
            $('#canvas').fadeOut(1);
            var url = $('#url')[0];
            url.value = "";
            $('#canvas').fadeIn(1);
            var cnvsH = 250;
            var cnvsW = img.naturalWidth * cnvsH / img.naturalHeight;
            var canvas = $('#canvas');
            canvas.attr('width', cnvsW);
            canvas.attr('height', cnvsH);
            var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, cnvsW, cnvsH);
        }
        img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});
```

**画像URL入力→描画開始または画像ファイルをアップロード→描画開始**
になっています。
なのでinputには画像を読み込むコードのみにし、描画するコードはcanvasのイベントとして一つにまとめたいです。
どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか。

私が初心者のため理解しにくい説明になっているかと思い、図とコード（もちろん機能しないです）で現状とやりたいことをまとめましたので、よろしければご確認ください。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
$(function () {
  //input url
  $('#url').change(function () {
    var file = $('#file')[0];
    file.value = "";
    var url = $('#url').val();
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      //canvasに送りたい
      img = $('#canvas');
    }
  });
  //input file
  $('#file').change(function () {
    var url = $('#url')[0];
    url.value = "";
    var file = this.files[0];
    var img = new Image();
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function (e) {
      img.onload = function () {
        //canvasに送りたい
        img = $('#canvas');
      }
    }
  });
  //canvasに画像が来たら発火
  $('#canvas').change(function(){
    var cnvsH = 500;
    var cnvsW = img.naturalWidth * cnvsH / img.naturalHeight;
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', cnvsW);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', cnvsH);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, cnvsW, cnvsH);
  });
  //エンコード？
});
```

canvasに描画した後に加工→保存する機能を実装する予定です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「ユーザから見える挙動は想定通り実装できたが、重複しているコードをまとめたい」という理解でよろしいでしょうか。

案のようにcanvasにイベントを起こして画像を伝えることも可能ですが、わざわざcanvasでイベントを起こす必要はありません。共通するコードを関数にして、それぞれのloadイベントで呼べばよいのです。

動くかどうかわかりませんが、コードは以下のようになります。

```
$('#url').change(function() {
  loadImageThenDraw(this.val());
});

$('#file').change(function() {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function(e) { loadImageThenDraw(e.target.result); };
  fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

function loadImageThenDraw(src) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = drawImageOnCanvas;
  img.src = src;
}

function drawImageOnCanvas(event) {
  $('#url')[0].value = '';
  $('#file')[0].value = '';
  var img = event.target;
  var canvas = $('#canvas');
  canvas.fadeOut(1);
  ...
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, cnvsW, cnvsH);
}
```

Comment: 重複するコードをまとめたいです。ご教示いただきありがとうございます。ご教示いただいたコードでサンプルを作りました（https://jsbin.com/gogedafice/1/edit?html,js,output）（drawImageOnCanvasの…は省略の意かと思い、サイズ指定などのコードを入れました。）が、動作しませんでした。ただ、fadeOutをfadeInにしたところ、ファイルのアップロードから描画に成功しました。（https://jsbin.com/rilodacoqi/edit?html,js,output）

Comment: loadImageThenDraw(this.val());→loadImageThenDraw(this.value);にして、fadeOutを消したらできました。https://jsbin.com/cuqajudosi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

ローカルファイルをFileReaderで読み込み、そのメモリ上の画像をURL化(Blob_URL)してimageなどに表示させることができます。
それを使用してCanvasオブジェクトにdrawImageすることもできます。

[JQuery ブラウザで画像ファイルを読み込んでサイズや形式を変換する](https://qiita.com/Urushibara01/items/e3f180ef4d0d03450ab1)
私が書いた物ですが、参考になりますでしょうか？